# Delayed Job Overwhelming DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

I have a method which updates all DNS records for an account with 1 delayed job for each record. There's a lot of workers and queues which is great for getting other jobs done quickly, but this particular job completes quickly and overwhelms the database. Because each job requires DNS to resolve, it's difficult to move this to a process which collects the information then writes once. So I'm instead looking for a way to stagger delayed jobs.

As far as I know, just using `sleep(0.1)` in the after method should do the trick. I wanted to see if anyone else has specifically dealt with this situation and solved it.

I've created a custom job to test out a few different ideas. Here's some example code:

```
def update_dns
  Account.active.find_each do |account|
    account.domains.where('processed IS NULL').find_each do |domain|
      begin
        Delayed::Job.enqueue StaggerJob.new(self.id)
      rescue Exception => e
        self.domain_logger.error "Unable to update DNS for #{domain.name} (id=#{domain.id})"
        self.domain_logger.error e.message
        self.domain_logger.error e.backtrace
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When a cron job calls Domain.update_dns, the delayed job table floods with tens of thousands of jobs, and the workers start working through them. There's so many workers and queues that even setting the lowest priority overwhelms the database and other requests suffer.

Here's the StaggerJob class:

```
class StaggerJob < Struct.new(:domain_id)

  def perform
    domain.fetch_dns_job
  end

  def enqueue(job)
    job.account_id      = domain.account_id
    job.owner           = domain
    job.priority        = 10 # lowest
    job.save
  end

  def after(job)
    # Sleep to avoid overwhelming the DB
    sleep(0.1)
  end

  private
    def domain
      @domain ||= Domain.find self.domain_id
    end

end
```

This may entirely do the trick, but I wanted to verify if this technique was sensible.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the problem, could you share a sample code? and explain more ?

Comment: Provided some details

Comment: So, the problem is too many jobs for Delayed Job?

Comment: The problem is the database can't handle the burst of writes while handling other requests. Right now I'm trying to solve the problem by giving it some breathing room, instead of rewriting the feature to collect the data and make fewer, larger writes. It seems to be the shortest path right now.

Comment: @Archonic I'm sure you don't want to hear it, but you ought to replace DJ with Resque or Sidekiq (preferred). It's not much work, and it's much better.

Comment: @coreyward It's not really my call but I'm curious about why you think they're better.

Comment: @Archonic Briefly: they don't try to serialize complex objects, they use smarter polling architecture, and they both support more complex functionality because they're made to be extensible. Oh, and FWIW, they're both much faster/have less overhead (especially Sidekiq). DJ used to be the easiest out-of-the-box solution, but that was years ago.

Comment: @coreyward Interesting! If there's a performance benefit, we'll def look into it. We have 13 sync servers :S

Comment: @Archonic Oh jesus. Yeah, they both use Redis, which is much lighter. [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) is also multithreaded, and intended to be used with substantial loads. You could probably replace all 13 of those with a single server unless your jobs are super heavy. Plus the creator, [Mike Perham](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1494519/mike-perham) answers questions here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the priority for these jobs were set to 0 (highest). Setting to 10 (lowest) helped. Sleeping in the job in the after method would work, but there's a better way.

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue StaggerJob.new(domain.id, :fetch_dns!), run_at: (Time.now + (0.2*counter).seconds) # stagger by 0.2 seconds
```

This ends up pausing outside the job instead of inside. Better!